# Torrent Tracker info hash GET Request- Python

Tags: python, http, urlencode, bittorrent, tracker

I'm trying to connect to a torrent tracker to receive a list of peers to play bit torrent with, however I am having trouble forming the proper GET request.

As far as I understand, I must obtain the 20 byte SHA1 hash of the bencoded 'info' section from the .torrent file. I use the following code:

```
h = hashlib.new('sha1')
h.update(bencode.bencode(meta_dict['info']))
info_hash =  h.digest()
```

This is where I am stuck. I can not figure out how to create the proper url-encoded info_hash to stick into a URL string as a parameter.

I believe it involves some combination of urllib.urlencode and urllib.quote, however my attempts have not worked so far.

Comment: urllib.quote() should be all you need...

Comment: on rare occasions, torrents have an info dict whose keys aren't lexicographically sorted, or contain duplicate keys. In such cases, your re-encoding of it would most likely yield a different byte sequence than the one in the .torrent file, and also the wrong hash. To deal with this, instead hash the original range in the .torrent file the corresponds to the info dict.

Answer (score 1):

well a bit late but might help someone.

Using module `requests` encodes the url by it's self. First you need to create a dictionary with the parameters (info_hash, peer_id etc). Then you only have to do a get request

```
response = requests.get(tracker_url, params=params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `urllib.quote_plus()` is all you need.